# Cocos2d iphone app runs oddly on actual iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, scaling

I have a simple application using Cocos2d, and all the images show up fine when running on the simulator. However, when i run it on an iphone, all the images are scaled up and incredible amount, making the game unplayable.

Has anyone got any ideas as to why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Different screen resolutions.  My guess is you're probably running the simulator as a Retina display and your iPhone is not a Retina?

Comment: use image.png for old devices and image-hd.png with double the size for retina iphones. in your code you don't need to reference to the "image-hd.png" file just load "image.png", cocos2d will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, and that was my initial thought too. But when i run the app on the simulator in retina display mode, it ran fine, all images the right size, but the same issue is still there with the actual iphone

Comment: Also, its scaled up massively, i'd have to set the scale of the CCSprites to 0.035 to get it close to its original size, and then some of the image is still cut off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the possibility that your simulator is running retina. Probably you are trying to display an image that is at the higher resolution on an older, non-retina device.

You can also just add the suffix "-hd" to any image, and then cocos2d will recognize it as being at the higher resolution automatically. But when you actually finish your app you will want to have 2 copies of each image, one at each resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and that was my initial thought too. But when i run the app on the simulator in retina display mode, it ran fine, all images the right size, but the same issue is still there with the actual iphone

Comment: Also, its scaled up massively, i'd have to set the scale of the CCSprites to 0.035 to get it close to its original size, and then some of the image is still cut off.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your app off your phone doing a clean build and reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was that when i initialised the sprite, using `spriteWithFile`, it set it to a certain size. When i changed the sprites texture later on, it kept the size of the last image, but had a different texture.